# scala_spark _dataframe_hivecontext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table. It contain some one column as "query" and there are 4 records in it. I will read the hive using :

```
val query_hive=sqlContext.sql(s"select * from hive_query limit 1")
```

I need to use this query in another hive for the calculation.

I have tried this method:

```
val ouput=sqlContext.sql(s"$query_hive")
```

But I am getting an error. Can anybody suggest the solution for the same?

Comment: The output of first query is already stored in `query_hive`. You have to define it as a String. Highly recommended : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: yes @philantrovert..I converted it into a string using the below :val ab=sqlContext.sql(s"select id  from hive1 where name='nikhil'").map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String]).Eventhough the below query is failing.
val abc=sqlContext.sql(s"select id  from hive1 where id=$ab")

Comment: Any idea about that?

Comment: You need to apply an action. Use `.collect` at the end where youre defining `ab`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You are not passing query correctly, just look it below:

```
scala> val query = "select * from src limit 1"
query: String = select * from src limit 1

scala> sql(s"""$query""").show
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
+---+-----+
```

Thanks.

Comment: In my case My query is not string.it is query_hive: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.

Comment: You are doing wrong. Your query is `s"select * from hive_query limit 1"`. what are you doing, you are passing the query into `sqlContext.sql` and it will return the DF. So you have to write your query into string then you can use it multiple time otherwise your use case will be different.

Comment: I will clear my question.I will query the hive table and I will be getting some values which are data frame. This value again i need to use in some other hive table.there I am failing

Comment: Do you want to use that value in `where` clause?

Comment: first hive o/p:select count(*) from abc;This again i need to use in another hivecontext to get the o/p

Comment: you have to fetch the value from DF and then you can use that value.

Comment: I am unable to pass df o/p to the new hiveContext.sql